# Reputation required for posting answer?

Tags: support, specific-question, protected-questions, reputation

I post frequently on other SE sites, and have been lurking here for some time. Finally, I came across [a question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/19140/how-would-a-dragon-be-used-in-a-modern-military) which I felt like I could answer, so I logged in and saw that the question had been protected. In the box, it states that `"Thank you for your interest in this question. Because it has attracted low-quality answers, posting an answer now requires 10 reputation on this site"`. However, I have the standard, free 100 rep as I have many accounts on other SEs. Is this a typo in the protected message box? Or is my reputation wonky? What's going on here? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The operative phrase is "10 reputation **on this site**". For the purposes of posting answers to a protected question, the association bonus (unfortunately, perhaps) doesn't count.

Since I'm the one who protected that question, perhaps a little bit of explanation is in order. For whatever reason, that question was attracting low-quality answers, drawing flags; it currently has one deleted answer, and another two that are accumulating delete votes. Aside from cleaning up after the fact, the only real option we have (which still allows answers to be posted at all) is protecting the question, which causes users who have not yet earned the 10 reputation on the specific site to not be able to post answers to that specific question.

Looking at your network profile, you seem to be a good contributor elsewhere on the network, and I'm sorry that people such as yourself get caught in the crossfire when something like this happens.

Bottom line: things are working as expected, and even though the message could be clearer, it does state why you are unable to post an answer.

The upside is that even a single upvote on a single answer elsewhere, or two upvotes on a question, will get you above the threshold. We have a pretty upvote-happy community. Surely there is *some* other question where you can contribute a useful answer in order to earn the necessary reputation.

**Note:** This has since been clarified in the text, which currently reads:

> Thank you for your interest in this question. Because it has attracted low-quality or spam answers that had to be removed, posting an answer now requires 10 [reputation](/help/whats-reputation) on this site (the [association bonus does not count](/help/privileges/new-user)).

Comment: No explanation necessary whatsoever. I agree 100% with that question being protected. I was in the infantry for twelve years and so rather itching to answer that question, but it's no problem at all and I completely understand. It makes perfect sense what you've explained, and thank you for taking the time to do so.

Comment: @L0j1k I hope that once you've earned a little rep here, you'll go back and answer it.  Welcome to Worldbuilding!